# Repository gone after Perforce server update

Tags: server, repository, perforce

I run perforce server on Ubuntu. Just typed apt-get upgrade and noticed that perforce server got updated as well. The thing is that I can't access repository any more. Is it gone for good? I'm hope that it's only matter of reconfigure, but I am a total newbie to perforce administration.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access your server after an upgrade, it's probably one of these three things:

1. Did you accidentally change the `P4ROOT` setting?  (This determines where your database lives and is unique to each server instance.)  If so, the server will start and you'll be able to connect to it, but it won't have the same contents it did before.  Setting `P4ROOT` to an empty directory and starting `p4d` will give you a fresh new server instance.  Setting `P4ROOT` to your existing server database directory and starting `p4d` will give you access to your existing server instance.
2. Does the new version require a manual database upgrade?  If so, you'll be unable to start `p4d` or connect to it via a client, and you'll see an error message in your log (`P4LOG`) telling you to run `p4d -xu`.  Do that to upgrade the database.
3. Does your license not support the new version (i.e. because it expired before this version was released)?  If so, you'll be unable to start `p4d`, and you'll see an error message in your log (`P4LOG`) telling you the license has expired.  Contact Perforce to renew your license, or downgrade `p4d` to stay on the version that you're licensed for.

Answer (score 0):

p4root was set wrong, fixing it helped.